# "Failed to create the part's controls" in SQLite browser triggered by org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.internal.lang.SqlJetParserException exception

Tags: android, sqlite, eclipse-plugin, android-sqlite

I have [QuestoID's CellObject SQLite browser](http://www.questoid.com/Tools/CellObjectSQLiteXMLBrowser.aspx) plugin installed on my eclipse as this was the most commonly described solution to visualize android dbs.

I have used it before without problems, but today (after a while before using it again) when trying to open a .db file on my emulator, I got the error message **"Failed to create the part's controls"**
  from the CellObject SQLite Browser.

If I click on details, I get a more detailed message with a

> org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.internal.lang.SqlJetParserException no
>   viable alternative at input 'value' regarding one of my tables.

I imagine that there is perhaps some corruption on the table but apparently not enough to fail in a **pragma integrity check** and I can open it with [Sqlite browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/).

Any idea how to solve this problem and to be able to see the db on  CellObject SQLite browser?